# Search multiple buffers without replacing

Tags: search, buffers

Opening all 49 files in my working folder in separate buffers, I wanted to see if there were any em dashes.

I typed `:bufdo /—` and vim immediately went to work, processing a page of buffers at a time. All but one file appeared to not contain my string. The thing is, I wasn’t able to check. Everything just wizzed by and I just happened to see that there was one file that wasn’t marked as “Pattern not found”. What I was expecting was for it to stop at the first occurrence and then let me use `n` and `N` to scroll through the search findings.

My question is, is there a way to search through multiple buffers (without replacing) in a way that behaves similarly to searching in a single buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `bufdo` runs a command (here, the ex command `:/`), so there's no real interactivity
2. For a search over multiple files (or buffers), use `:grep`/`:vimgrep`. For example:

```
:grep -R pat .
" or
:vimgrep /pat/ **/*
" or whatever you need
```

Then you navigate with the quickfix list (`:help quickfix`). Probably `:cnext`/`:cprevious` are useful, or `:cwindow` if you want to browse the list of matches.

Comment: vimgrep worked. Is there a way of specifying a range in each file similar to `:10,$`? (I have a yaml header and need to search for stray hyphens in the text while avoiding the six hyphens in the yaml section.)

Comment: @BrianWilson `:help /\%>l` (the last character is a lowercase L)

Comment: Thank you! For those following along at home the full command was :vimgrep /\%>10l-/ *.txt